# Mysql comparison of curtime() with a constant in utf8

Tags: mysql, datetime, utf-8, collation

I don't understand why the following comparison don't work in utf8 (mysql 5.5.27 - dotdeb).

```
select '00:00:00' < curtime();
```

Can you explain how mysql evaluates this expression because I don't see any logical reasons why this is not working :

```
mysql> set names 'utf8';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select '00:00:00' < curtime();
ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '<'

mysql> set names 'latin1';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select '00:00:00' < curtime();
+------------------------+
| '00:00:00' < curtime() |
+------------------------+
| 1 |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec
```

An other example, it works if the comparison is done in a certain order :

```
mysql> set names 'utf8';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select '00:00:00' < curtime();
ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '<'
mysql> select curtime() > '00:00:00';
+------------------------+
| curtime() > '00:00:00' |
+------------------------+
| 1 |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The collation and character variables in utf8 :

```
mysql> show variables like 'collation%';
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like 'character%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is working with MariaDb (5.5.25-MariaDB)

```
MariaDB [(none)]> set names 'utf8';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> select '00:00:00' < curtime();
+------------------------+
| '00:00:00' < curtime() |
+------------------------+
|                      1 |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to compare different data types - string and time, in this case MySQL uses type conversion and throws an error. Try to use STR_TO_DATE function to convert string to TIME and compare two identical types:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('00:00:00', '%H:%i:%s') < CURTIME();
```

More information here - [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html).

Comment: yes, it works also wih `select cast('00:00:00' as TIME) < curtime();` but i'm trying to understand why the type conversion doesn't work

Comment: I think MySQL doesn't know how to compare two strings with different collations - 'utf8_general_ci' and 'binary'; at the same time it can compare some other different collations like 'latin1_swedish_ci' and 'binary'. Try this query to view collations - SELECT COLLATION('00:00:00'), COLLATION(CURTIME());

Comment: but it works with select curtime() > '00:00:00'; very strange behavior so I've opened http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=66480

Comment: ...maybe MySQL pays attention on first operand.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution, its working.
You need to cast value to time.

Eg 1 -

```
select cast('00:00:00' as time) < curtime();
```

Eg 2 -

```
CURTIME()<= ADDTIME(time_column,'-00:15:00')
```